# Count and generate a constant in SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas-macro

For each id count the number of qc=fails, generate a new column final with all values as "repeat" if any one id has 2 or more than 2 fails, else pass. Repeat if count is greater than equal to 2. For some reason the if-else statement does not work. Instead of the final being a repeat for count greater than equal to 2, it is displaying it as pass.[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlMop.png)

```
%let repeat_flag = 0;
%let pass_flag = 0;
data _null_;
  set exp;
  if count ge 2 then call symputx ('repeat_flag',1);
    else call symputx ('pass_flag',1);
  stop;
run;
%if &repeat_flag %then %do;
  data exp;
    set exp;
        Final = 'REPEAT';
  run;
%end;
%if &pass_flag %then %do;
  data exp;
    set exp;
        Final = 'PASS';
  run;
%end;
```

%put &repeat_flag;
%put &pass_flag;

Comment: You are not counting anything in this code.  You are testing the value of COUNT for the first observation in EXP.  Was that your intent?

Comment: Hello @Tom, testing the count, Yes. For the count column, if count is more than equal to 2, generate a new column (Final) with all values as Repeat or else all values in the Final column equal to Pass.

Comment: If WHICH value of COUNT is greater than 2?  How many observations are in EXP dataset? Your code is only testing the value in the first observation.  Do you want to test if ANY value is larger than 2?

Comment: Yes, if any is larger than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test if any observation has COUNT larger than one then use a pattern like this instead.  Set the macro variable to the FALSE condition and then set it TRUE when the condition is met.

```
%let pass_flag=PASS;
data _null_;
  set exp;
  if count ge 2 then do;
     call symputx ('pass_flag','REPEAT');
     stop;
  end;
run;
data want;
  set exp;
  length final $6;
  final="&pass_flag" ;
run;
```